# Undefined local variable error with simple program that adds items to array

Tags: ruby

```
class Books
    attr_accessor :name, :book_id
    def initialize(name, book_id)
        @name = name,
        @book_id = book_id
    end
end

class BookCollection
    def intialize
        @book_names = []
    end

    def add_to_books(book_name)
        book_name.push(book_names)
    end
end

book1 = Books.new("catch22", "12345")
book_collection1 = BookCollection.new
book_collection1.add_to_books(book1.name)
puts book_collection1
```

end

That is my code and the error I'm getting is "undefined local variable or method `book_names'". I tried adding "    attr_accessor :book_names" and when I do that the printed output doesn't make sense.

Comment: Don't you mean `@book_names.push(book_name)`?  Also, instead of `puts book_collection` you need a method (e.g., `attr_reader`) to return @book_names.

Comment: If your question was answered, please select an answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few mistakes in your code:

- line 4 should not end with a comma.
- `initialize` in `class BookCollection` is misspelled, resulting in `@book_names` not being initialized.  `@book_names` therefore equals `nil` when you attempt to add an element to it with `push`.  `nil` does not have a method `push`; hence the exception, and the message printed with the exception.
- `book_name.push(book_names)` should be `@book_name.push(book_name)`.  (`@book_name` must be an instance_variable, as opposed to a local variable, to be visible outside a method, within the class definition.
- `puts book_collection1` prints the class instance; you want to print `@book_names`.

Here I've fixed your code.  I've used `<<` instead of `push`.  Either is OK, but the former seems to be favored my most.

```
class Books
  attr_accessor :name, :book_id
  def initialize(name, book_id)
  puts "name = #{name}, book_id = #{book_id}"
    @name = name
    @book_id = book_id
  end
end

class BookCollection
  attr :book_names
  def initialize
    @book_names = []
  end    
  def add_to_books(book_name)
    @book_names << book_name
  end
end

book_collection1 = BookCollection.new
book1 = Books.new("Catch22", "12345")
book2 = Books.new("Hawaii", "67890")
book_collection1.add_to_books(book1.name)
book_collection1.add_to_books(book2.name)

book_collection1.book_names # => ["Catch22", "Hawaii"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably just a typo at

```
book_name.push(book_names)
```

Should have been

```
book_names.push(book_name)
```

With `attr_accessor :book_names`

Comment: You forgot to slap a `@` on the front of `book_names`.

Comment: I made all the changes and still get "`add_to_books': undefined method `push'". Btw, why is the @ necessary? I was told before that you didn't need it. @CarySwoveland

Comment: Right, there was no `attr_accessor` for `book_names`.